# Delphi : Create a RichText in a formless unit

Tags: delphi, trichedit

How do you mimick a TRichEdit in a formless unit?

I want to be able to add formatted text to it.

After all processes have been processes have been perform then the finally will pass the formatted data as a param to an actual TRichEdit...

TIA

Comment: If I remember right, a rich edit control requires a parent window of some sort. You can declare, create, and use it from another unit, but upon creation you must assign it a parent form.

Comment: Use a [Windowless RichEdit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787609(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Windowless rich edit is the "right" way to do this. For a cheap and nasty alternative create a hidden form, make a TRichEdit with that form as its parent and put a cloths peg on your nose.

Comment: Up-voted comment for the "peg on your nose".  :)

Comment: There's an example of using a windowless RichEdit from Delphi by [Rob Kennedy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy) at GitHub [here](https://gist.github.com/rkennedy/1482014). See the `TOM.pas` unit.

Comment: @RobKennedy's code is essential because this interface is erroneously declared with fastcall calling convention, and thus unreachable from Delphi. Rob's code solves that.